# get first element from a list without exception

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider this code

```
description = ""
desc = hxs.select('/html/head/meta[2]/@content').extract()
if len(desc) > 0:
    description = desc[0]       
item["description"] = description
```

desc is a list of strings. If list is empty description is an empty string, if not it's the first elements from the list. How to make it more pythonic?

Forgot to mention that I have to use 2.7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can write:

```
desc = hxs.select("/html/head/meta[2]/@content").extract()
item["description"] = desc[0] if len(desc) > 0 else ""
```

As pointed out in the comments below, you can also directly evaluate the list in a boolean context:

```
item["description"] = desc[0] if desc else ""
```

Comment: `if len(desc) > 0` could be replaced by `if len(desc)`.

Comment: @Waleed, yup, it can. I've become used to specifying the entire condition since C# forces me to do so, but it is indeed not required in Python.

Comment: @WaleedKhan or just `if desc`, since empty lists are falsy.

Comment: Or `item["description"] = desc and desc[0] or ""` if this needs to work on earlier pythons that would choke on the 'else' part.

Comment: @tdelaney witch python version?

Comment: @lukas - not exactly sure. the if..else doesn't work on python 2.4 (standard python on rhel 5.x) but does work on 2.7. I think it started in 2.6 but am not sure.

Comment: @tdelaney, [version 2.5](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html), to be specific.

Comment: It's not just that you _can_ just directly evalute the list in a boolean context; you _should_. As [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says, "For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false."

Comment: @abarnert, I was thinking the same way a few years ago, but since then I got used to specify the condition explicitly and I do think the result is a little more readable. After all, as the Zen of Python says, *explicit is better than implicit*. Your mileage may vary, of course :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: But you're being explicit about the wrong thing. You care about the emptiness of the list, not the length; the fact that using the length to check the emptiness might be the fastest way to do that is irrelevant. (And the fact that it might not means it may even be harmful.)

Answer (score 15):

Alternately you could use make use of the fact that [next](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) supports a default

```
item["description"]  = next(iter(desc), "")
```

Comment: To those that are wondering [what is iterable](https://imgur.com/FHK8FVX.png) in Python

Comment: Note that this is not idempotent.  (Meaning that `next()` will only return the first element the first time it is called).

Answer (score 1):

You can use exception handling (although it's more verbose than using the conditional expression).

```
desc = hxs.select('/html/head/meta[2]/@content').extract()
try:
    description = desc[0]
except IndexError:
    description = ""
```

Comment: It may be more verbose, but that doesn't mean it's worse. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) say: "This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C."

Comment: In this case, both approaches are so simple and readable that I would probably choose the conditional expression as the shorter approach :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should actually do this in your case, but for completeness…

For an *iterator* that might be empty, you just use the optional default value for [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
desc = foo.finditer(bar)
item["description"] = next(desc, "")
```

Meanwhile, you can always use `iter()` to "peek" at the iterator you would get from a sequence (or other non-iterator iterable).

So:

```
desc = foo.findall(bar)
item["description"] = next(iter(desc), "")
```

I think this is less readable than just using the list as a sequence (whether you use chepner's [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) answer or Frédéric Hamidi's [LYBL](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl)) rather than just an iterable. After all, we have the sequence API for a reason.